# Contents line titles are not always flushed right

Tags: sectioning, titletoc

I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,titletoc}

\titlecontents*{section}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\\ \bfseries\text{Chapter } \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bf\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First Chapter}
\section{Second Chapter}
\subsection{First subsection}
\section{Third Chapter}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\begin{thebibliography}{99} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\ \\ \bf References}
\bibitem{x} xyz
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following contents list:

[image]

My problem is that the formatting of the "first chapter" is not correct, namely the page number is not flushed all the way to the right and there is no extra line space before chapter 2. I have noticed that, for some reason, both problems go away if the first chapter has a subsection - see example below - but I do not want to include a subsection in my first chapter so I am stuck here.

Thanks to all help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most latex problems can be solved by not using `\\` :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,titletoc}

\titlecontents*{section}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\ifhmode\unskip\fi\endgraf\bfseries\text{Chapter } \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {\bf}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bf\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First Chapter}
\section{Second Chapter}
\subsection{First subsection}
\section{Third Chapter}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\begin{thebibliography}{99} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibitem{x} xyz
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```